# How to check if an array/hash key exists before calling it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print the value of an array/hash key without raising exception when the index is not found. (note I'm not looking for rescue here)

```
<%= content.categories[0].name %>
```

In the above statement, if categories is an empty array, it will throw an exception. Since I'm using this code in my views, I want a code that is very brief and yet prints nothing if categories is empty.

Comment: `Hash#[]` and `Array#[]` do not raise an error when the key/index is not found. It is `name` that is raising an error.

Comment: @sawa `nil.name` will definitely raise an error though.

Comment: @meagar Sure. To give a good suggesttion to the OP, the OP has to tell when (on what class) `name` is defined.

Comment: @sawa No, the best solution for this particular problem (see my answer) doesn't care what `categories` may or may not contain. The point is that it's `nil`. It's `nil` regardless of what kind of *other* class may appear in that array on a different invocation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue isn't that you're accessing an empty array, that much is fine. Accessing an undefined index of an array will evaluate to `nil`. The issue is that you're attempting to invoke a method on that `nil`, which raises a `NoMethodError`.

Use [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Object/try), it's specifically meant to solve the problem you're having, which is that you're lazily avoiding checking for `nil` before invoking a method:

```
<%= content.categories[0].try(:name) %>
```

You can even chain `try` again, though excessive use of `try` should be avoided:

```
<%= content.categories[0].try(:name).try(:length) %>
```

Alternatively, you could be using traditional flow-control statements:

```
<%= content.categories[0].name if content.categories[0] %>
```

Comment: I think it is worth noting that [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) as changed in Rails 4 and there's now [`try!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try-21) if you still want the Rails 3 behavior.

Comment: @muistooshort Worth noting I suppose, though in this case it doesn't matter; as I understand it, the new behaviour only matters of `try` is invoked on a non-`nil` object. We're *definitely* dealing with `nil.try` here.

Comment: thanks @meagar for understanding my requirement and giving a solution though I was wrong in analysing the problem. Your solution helps my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
content.categories.tap{|a| break a[0].name unless a.empty?}
```